# Does Liquibase diff give you data difference between two dbs?

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to migrate data from one oracle db to another. I generated difference between them using:

```
./liquibase --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:CMS/password@docker-ygupta.domain.com:1522/ORCL --username=cms --password=password diffChangeLog --referenceDriver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --referenceUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:CMS/password@172.18.41.67:1521/ORCL  --referenceUsername=cms --referencePassword=password > dchangelog.xml
```

Now I generated sql of this dchangelog.xml using updateSQL as below:

```
<username>cms</username>
<password>password</password>
<url>jdbc:oracle:thin:CMS/password@172.18.41.111:1522/ORCL</url>
<execution>
        <id>process</id>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>updateSQL</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <username>cms</username>
            <password>password</password>
            <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:CMS/password@docker-ygupta.domain.com:1522/ORCL</url>
            <changeLogFile>${output.change.log.file}.xml</changeLogFile>
            <migrationSqlOutputFile>${output.change.log.file}.sql</migrationSqlOutputFile>
            <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
        </configuration>
</execution>
```

What I get in this SQL is just difference of columns, foreign keys, unique constraints, index etc. What I wanted was data which was not generated.

I looked into documentation it says [here](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html):

Currently, Liquibase runs the following comparisons:

```
Version Differences
Missing/unexpected tables
Missing/unexpected views
Missing/unexpected columns
Missing/unexpected primary keys
Missing/unexpected unique constraints
Missing/unexpected foreign Keys
Missing/unexpected sequences
Missing/unexpected indexes
Column definition differences (data type, auto-increment, etc.)
View definition differences
**Data differences (limited), not checked by default**
```

Is it even supported because if i try to run from command line it gives error:

> [ygupta@nrvdevops02 WS]$ ./liquibase
>   --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:CMS/password@docker-ygupta.domain.com:1522/ORCL
>   --username=cms --password=password diffChangeLog --referenceDriver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --referenceUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:CMS/password@172.18.41.67:1521/ORCL --referenceUsername=cms --referencePassword=password --diffTypes=data Starting Liquibase at Fri, 14 Dec 2018 17:55:18 AEDT (version 3.6.2
>   built at 2018-07-03 11:28:09) Errors:   Including 'diffTypes=data' in
>   the diffChangeLog command has no effect. This option should only be
>   used with the 'generateChangeLog' command.

@SteveDonie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is accurate. It is not possible to use the `diffChangeLog` command to do data differences between two databases.

Liquibase really is not a suitable tool for doing much with data. It is primarily intended as a schema change management tool.